# Latex Command to Compile another Latex File

Tags: compiling, automation, attachfile

I am making a cover letter, where I add a CV to that letter. I currently use the command

```
\includepdf[pages={-}]{CV.pdf}
```

Using the package `pdfpages` to include another pdf file. This imply that `CV.tex` have to be manually compiled before compiling the cover letter (`cover_Letter.tex`). Is there a command that could be added to automatically compile `CV.tex` inside of the `cover_Letter.tex`?

Comment: You could use Arara.

Comment: A shell script (or batch file for Windows) is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's problematic because your already running LaTeX compiler has to call itself again. I've made the experience that if LaTeX compiles two files at the same time it will almost always crash. It just seems not to be designed to allow multiple instances (well, Win with MikTeX at least).

I recommend you write your own script which runs `CV.tex` first and after `cover_letter.tex` or you use Arara or any other nice tool for the job.

Comment: Except that lots of packages rely on sub-processes for e.g. the externalisation of images with TikZ, standalone, forest, pgfplots, inclusion of inline MetaPost etc. So unless none of these things work on Windows with MikTeX, the general claim you make is demonstrably false. Note that multiple instances is not the same thing as running another compilation in a sub-shell, for example. (Multiple instances don't seem problematic on my system, but you might be right that Windows can't handle those. But that is a different issue.)